# Alternativa para Classe NuSoap

Tags: php, soap

Estou utilizando a classe NuSoap para fazer um webservice.

Porém, quando temos a versão do php para 7.0 ou maior, tenho problemas com códigos que são depreciados para essa versão.

Gostaria de saber se existe uma alternativa para a classe Nusoap que funcione na versão 7.0 do php.

Atualmente alterei a versão do php no hosting que estou trabalhando para a versão 5.6 e aparentemente funcionou. Ou teria uma outra forma de fazer um webservice?

Comment: NuSoap é uma biblioteca (3rd party) desenvolvida para o PHP 4 e portada para o PHP 5. No PHP 5, existe a biblioteca nativa denominada [PHP SOAP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php), ela é a indicada em qualquer versão do PHP >= 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Particularmente eu sempre utilizei a biblioteca nativa do PHP (que está disponível tanto para php5 quanto para php7) para criação de webservices em SOAP, segue documentação: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.soap.php.

Não conheço outra alternativa, mas essa sempre foi útil.